# Allow apache external access only to specified domain

Tags: apache-2.4

I am having two servers on serves web(xy.power.com) running under load balancer  and another on is api services(api.power.com)

now i have requirement to block access for all external users except users from web api calls form xy.power.com

please provide you suggestions and ideas.

regards,
asaguru

Comment: Unclear if you mean from or to?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this to your virtual server config

```
<Location />
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xy.power.com
</Location>
```

## OR

A slightly better approach for you would be to add this to your .htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xy.power.com
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer but my web server are running behind load balancer i dont have static ip , is it possible to allow based on domain name (xy.power.com).

Comment: Somewhere along the line, there will be a static IP pointing to your site. Since you're using some cloud hosting system, that means other sites share the same IP, but that shouldn't really be a problem. Either way, I've updated my answer to something that should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer my website static ip will change automatically, so it is very risk to go by ip based.

Comment: Okay well use the hostname xy.power.com like I edited my answer to show